# Adding arguments to __init__ of ConfigParser

Tags: python, inheritance

I want to extend SafeConfigParser with some functionality by inheriting from it:

```
class ExtendedConfigParser(SafeConfigParser):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        SafeConfigParser.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

..but have a problem with SafeConfigParser's init:

```
    SafeConfigParser.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'config_file'
```

I could get around the problem by deleting added kw arguments from kwargs, but I wonder if there is a more elegant solution? (note: it seems that SafeConfigParser is an old-style class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're inheriting from Python's `SafeConfigParser` and you're trying to instantiate `ExtendedConfigParser` like this:

```
cfg_parser = ExtendedConfigParser(config_file='my_file.cfg')
```

If that's the case, then `SafeConfigParser` doesn't have any keyword argument named `config_file` which is where the error is coming from.

A function declaration in python allows you to specify arguments, keyword arguments, and then *it allows unspecified arguments and keyword arguments through `*args` and `**kwargs`*. I'm assuming you're wanting to access `config_file` *only* in `ExtendedConfigParser` and *not* in `SafeConfigParser`.

All you need to do is change your `__init__` parameters in `ExtendedConfigParser`:

```
class ExtendedConfigParser(SafeConfigParser):

    def __init__(config_file='', *args, **kwargs):
        self.config_file = config_file
        SafeConfigParser.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

This allows you specify any needed parameters for `ExtendedConfigParser` and then passes any additional parameters on to `SafeConfigParser`'s constructor.

Comment: I dimly remember that kw arguments can only be specified last (i.e. not before positions arguments, and after all *args are positional arguments, just unknown ones), which is why I did not take your approach here - but does this apply only to kw arguments in **kwargs or named args in general?

Comment: A function/method is declared as parameters needed for that function, then you can specify a "*catchall*" for any other argument or keyword argument (`*args` or `**kwargs`). There is a specific order that the arguments are declared: positional arguments, keyword arguments *then* you specify the catchall for positional arguments, then keyword arguments. I used a keyword argument `config_file` based on the error message you received.
Example of the order: 
`fn(arg1, arg2, kwarg1='', kwarg2='', *args, **kwargs)`